# Filter data based on date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

Im trying to execute the following SQL query and filter out the data based on the date.

I need to display a table which filters out the data such that, only those rows which are between the mentioned start_date and end_date

Here's the query that I have been trying

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.column1, T1.column2, T2.START_DATE, T2.END_DATE
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE (T1.column1= T2.column2) AND
(T2.START_DATE >= '15/01/2013 10:58:58' AND 
   T2.END_DATE <= '18/01/2013 10:58:58') ORDER BY T2.START_DATE DESC
```

I get the result with values from 2012 as well. Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: Try using the ANSI format of 2013-01-15 10:58:58 and see how it goes

Comment: Do you have errors in your data, are there END_DATEs that are before START_DATEs. If you added a where clause END_DATE > START_DATE does this fix the problem?

Comment: What is the data type for `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` columns ?

Comment: @PeterJ - I can't change now,will I be able to do that in varchar format only?
I have checked if END_DATEs occur before START_DATEs There are no errors in the data; .
 Data type is VARCHAR(), I don't want to change that to date now;

Comment: You should convert all to dates to compare. Then you may truncate your dates unless you need hour/second difference in your output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned about any errors, if `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are `DATETIME` data type, there is nothing wrong with your query.  If you are not getting the correct records, Please check the data.

However your `date format may trouble you in a different server`. There are some good practices you could adhere to avoid such issues.

> -Whenever date is used as a string, try to use it in **ISO or ISO8601**
>   format (ie **'yyyymmdd'** or **'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm'**)
>
> -Also avoid joining tables with **WHERE Table1, Table2** which is old and
>   obsolete. JOINs are much better performed, neat and tidy.

You can change your query as follows;

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.column1, T1.column2, T2.START_DATE, T2.END_DATE
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.column1 = T2.column2
WHERE (T2.START_DATE >= '20130115 10:58:58' AND 
       T2.END_DATE <= '20130118 10:58:58') 
ORDER BY T2.START_DATE DESC
```

Comment: This issue is mainly because of the data types, the data type of both START_DATE and END_DATE is VARCHAR. 
Now i can't change the datatype.....
I have to somehow deal with the string. Will I be able to do this?

Comment: Can you show the format you have stored your dates in START_DATE and END_DATE fields? If they are in correct formats, you can Convert them to datetime before comparing. Ex; WHERE (CONVERT(datetime,T2.start_date) >= '20130115 10:58:58' AND  CONVERT(datetime,T2.end_date) <= '20130118 10:58:58')