# Display record from database filtering by date

Tags: sql

Can someone show me how to display records filtered by date range using SQL query.

For example; I want to display student name who was admitted between 10 sep 2015 to 10 aug 2015.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter data based on date in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397569/filter-data-based-on-date-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query for displaying records from database using date filter:

```sql
SELECT StudentName FROM Student WHERE Admitted BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

You then use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to specify the two parameters.

***Note:*** Never insert parameters into SQL using string concatenation. Always use `PreparedStatement`, or your code will be susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

As the javadoc of [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says:

> The object used for executing a **static** SQL statement and returning the results it produces.